# Are there any refactoring tools for Emacs C++ Programming?

Tags: c++, emacs, refactoring

Just like eclipse does, extracting function, renaming a variable, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer seems to be `xrefactory` from http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html

Answer (score 2):

[CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) has some features like what you're looking for.

Comment: AFAIK CEDET has no refactoring tools built in, in fact looking at your link there is no reference to such tools at all.

Comment: The "Find References" link would be helpful when refactoring.  I do not know of actual refactoring tools for Emacs, but I thought I'd reference the closest thing I knew of.

Comment: I wasn't previously aware of CEDET and, while it may not directly address the original question, it looks very appealing.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing as advanced as Eclipses's refactoring tools for emacs, the best you have is search/replace with well crafted regular expressions.